# why I can't insert datagen in flink?

Tags: sql, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, apache-hudi

```
Flink SQL> CREATE TABLE sourceT (
>   uuid varchar(20),
>   name varchar(10),
>   age int,
>   ts timestamp(3),
>   `partition` varchar(20)
> ) WITH (
>   'connector' = 'datagen',
>   'rows-per-second' = '1'
> );
[INFO] Execute statement succeed.

Flink SQL> create table t2(
>   uuid varchar(20),
>   name varchar(10),
>   age int,
>   ts timestamp(3),
>   `partition` varchar(20)
> )
> with (
>   'connector' = 'hudi',
>   'path' = '/tmp/hudi_flink/t2',
>   'table.type' = 'MERGE_ON_READ'
> );
[INFO] Execute statement succeed.

Flink SQL> insert into t2 select * from sourceT;
[INFO] Submitting SQL update statement to the cluster...
2022-11-29 11:55:39,776 WARN  org.apache.flink.yarn.configuration.YarnLogConfigUtil        [] - The configuration directory ('/opt/module/flink-1.13.6/conf') already contains a LOG4J config file.If you want to use logback, then please delete or rename the log configuration file.
2022-11-29 11:55:40,018 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy                        [] - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop163/192.168.10.163:8032
2022-11-29 11:55:40,151 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2022-11-29 11:55:40,224 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - Found Web Interface hadoop163:45413 of application 'application_1669685396475_0006'.
[INFO] SQL update statement has been successfully submitted to the cluster:
Job ID: 9f2283c2f6d943c170068abe39747bc0


Flink SQL> select * from t2;
2022-11-29 11:55:57,226 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient [] - SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2022-11-29 11:55:57,516 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy                        [] - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop163/192.168.10.163:8032
2022-11-29 11:55:57,516 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2022-11-29 11:55:57,520 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - Found Web Interface hadoop163:45413 of application 'application_1669685396475_0006'.
[INFO] Result retrieval cancelled.
```

Comment: This question is lacking what's actually the log or problem that's being encountered. There's also no used version available. Without this information, it's not possible to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Your query was submitted successfully to YARN.

You need to open the YARN UI to find any real cause for your query to get cancelled.